# Shipping method are not showing on shipping page

Tags: magento2, frontend, shipping-methods

Shipping method are not showing on shipping page

> Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Please check in admin you have shipping method enable and matching criteria to current cart!

Comment: have you enable it from admin?

Comment: can happen if the product is virtual, and this can easily happen by mistake if product has no weight

Answer (score 0):

First you goes the this path

```
Stores > Configuration > Sales > Shipping Methods > Enable any one shipping methods
```

[image]

You Enable the one shipping methods and you take care enable the shipping method all countries.

And other your website is multi store. So select the store view and the and select the your store and enable the shipping method above types.